# css change child position if parent element out of view

Tags: html, css

If the parent element is on view, the child element should be at the bottom of the parent. If the parent is outside of the view, the child should be 10px above the view.

```
<ng-scrollbar class="scroll">
   <div class=parent>
      <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
</ng-scrollbar>

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.parent:not(:in-viewport) .child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: auto;
  top: -10px;
}
```

Something like that, but the pseudo-class 'in-viewport' doesn't work. Is there a way without using javascript?

Comment: _"but the pseudo-element 'in-viewport' doesn't work"_ - that would be a pseudo _class_, not an element. And where did you even find this ...? Never seen that anywhere before. Is there some documentation for this that you can point to?

Comment: I didn't see it anywhere, it's just an example for what I want to do.

Comment: LOL, you phrased it as if you had a reasonable expectation for this to work ... _"Is there a way without using javascript?"_ - not that I can see. `position: sticky` is not going to work for your requirements, and other than that there isn't any "dynamic" way of positioning.

Comment: I think you'll need JS - CSS isn't really 'aware' of when an element is within view. And, depending on how much of the parent has to be in the viewport or  not in your two scenarios, you may find IntersectionObserver useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ng-scrollbar class="scroll">
   <div class=parent>
      <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
</ng-scrollbar>

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.scroll .ng-scrollbar-wrapper[verticalused="true"] .child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
}
```